# Where can I find a digital copy of《实用速成汉语》Chinese Made Easier?

Tags: resources

I'm looking for a digital copy of《实用速成汉语》Chinese Made Easier.

[Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/7561323603) seems to only have paperback copies.

I'm not seeing any mention of a digital copy on their own website: [CME](https://www.chinesemadeeasier.com/news.html).

Ideas?

Comment: Try this magical website https://sg1lib.org/book/11769807/fed32f

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried taobao?

If you can't find it, taobao has a service: send them a book, they return a pdf and a word document.

Excellent service, I highly recommend it!

They also rebind your book and return it.

I can send you the link if you can't find it.

I recently sent a big old German grammar textbook, I was very satisfied with the results.

Comment: What is the name of this service?

Comment: https://detail.tmall.com/item.htm?spm=a230r.1.14.16.5aab5d492rR67k&id=623201073725&ns=1&abbucket=7

Comment: Or just put 书成PDF in taobao, look for the black and white sign: 寄书扫描, very near the top

Answer (score 0):

Other than mentioned Taobao, local printing shops and libraries usually also provide scanning service.

Comment: Why are there delete votes? Please comment.